# Give a vector pair $(b,δb)$ for which $\dfrac{\|δx\|_2}{\|x\|_2}=k_2(A)\dfrac{\|δb\|_2}{\|b\|_2}$ holds

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, svd, condition-number, singular-values

> The condition number of a matrix gives a sharp estimate of the sensitivity
>   of $x$ with respect to perturbations of $b$ when solving $Ax = b$, this means
>   there exists a right hand side $b$ and a perturbation $δb$ such that
>
> $\dfrac{\|δx\|_2}{\|x\|_2}=k_2(A)\dfrac{\|δb\|_2}{\|b\|_2}$
>
> Where $k_2(A)$ is the condition number of $A.$
>
> Give a vector pair $(b, δb)$ for which this equality holds.

This is how far i get:

We know that $k_2(A)=\dfrac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_m},$ because we are in the 2-norm. ($\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_m$ are the maximal resp. minimal singular value of $A.$

By theorem, we know that we achieve equality when $b$ is a multiple of a left singular value of $A$ corresponding to the maximal singular value $\sigma_1$. Then let $b=ku_1$ for some scalar $k$. When solving for $Ax=b$ using the SVD we get $x=\frac{k}{\sigma_1}v_1$, where $v_1$ is a right singular vector corresponding to $\sigma_1$.

So now this is what i have:

$x=\frac{k}{\sigma_1}v_1$

$b=ku_1$ for some scalar $k$.

$\|db\|_2=\sigma_m \|dx\|_2$

But now im completely lost into finding the vector $db$. There is another thread with this question but i do not get anything from the answers there. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: this question has a duplicate here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2440257/find-a-vector-pair-b-%CE%B4b-for-which-dfrac-%CE%B4x-2-x-2-k-2a-dfrac?rq=1